# How to pass multiple DB data into jQuery's Autocomplete (AJAX) in Laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I'm using **jQuery's Autocomplete** to get data while the user is typing. It works; I get some *zipcode* that matches the user's input.

The thing is that **I want to pass more than the zipcode, like the neighborhood associated with that zipcode.** **Both are in the same table**.

**I want to pass the zipcode AND the neighborhood in the autocomplete.**

[image]

**Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace Grupo_Villanueva\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function buscarCp(Request $request)
    {

        $term = $request->input('term');

        $results = [];

        $queries = DB::connection('db_postalcodes')
            ->table('postal_code')
            ->where('postal_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%') //search 'postal_code' column
            ->take(10)
            ->get(); // get 5 results

        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            $results[] = [
                'postal_code' => $query->postal_code,
                'value' => $query->postal_code,
                'colonia' => $query->neighborhood];
        }

        return Response::json($results);
    }
}
```

I thought about fetching it with the `colonia` inside the associative array, though I'm not an expert.

**JS:**

```
@if (Request::is('admin/posts/create'))
{{-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script> --}}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.postalCode').autocomplete({
        source: "{{ route('busqueda-cp') }}",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#postalCode').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
</script>
@else
<!-- No se cargó select2-->
@endif
```

Route:

```
// Aquí se guarda la función que hace, vía ajax, búsqueda de código postal.
Route::get('/buscarCp', 'SearchController@buscarCp')->name('busqueda-cp');
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to append the neighborhood to the zip code? In your `$results` you can do this: `'value' => $query->postal_code . ' ' . $query->neighborhood,`

Comment: @newUserName02 Works. Thanks. Questions: **So could I append any number of data that way?**. Also, answer the question so I can select you as the winner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings together using `.` between strings. In your `$results` variable:

```
'value' => $query->postal_code . ' ' . $query->neighborhood,
```

You can concatenate any number of strings together this way:

```
$query->postal_code . ' ' . $query->neighborhood . ' (' . $query->foo . ') ' . $query->bar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep the array value from php you could use autocomplete's `_renderItem` method as seen [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

So your code would look like this:

```
$('.postalCode').autocomplete({
    source: "{{ route('busqueda-cp') }}",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#postalCode').val(ui.item.value);
    }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( item.postal_code + " " + item.colonia )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Then you could use the value and just change the way the select items look.